# Angular/Firebase/Password

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an angular project set up with Firebase. I have a Create user form. It works perfectly when I create the user, and it displayed in firebase Users

But when I try to log in, it says the password is incorrect. But I 100% sure the password is correct.

Can someone explain to me how is this possible or where is my mistake?

```
onLogin() {
  let email: string = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
  let password: string = this.loginForm.get('password').value; 
  this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(
    () => {
      this.router.navigate(['home'])
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: "it says the password is incorrect " => Where does it "say" that? Can you add a `catch` block and report what you see in the browser console? `.then(...).catch(err => {console.log(error)})`

Comment: core.js:5980 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.   @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Please console log the email and password before submission to verify that they are the right values. Make sure you are also trimming the values for white space